# How do find the number of revenue per user with a start date for a specific amount of days

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Say you have a table of users with the date they signed up.
And another table with their revenue 
How could we calculate the amount of revenue say for 6 months or 9 months of each member since they signed up using mySQL command?

Table 1 has 2 columns: 1. user_id 2. date_of_join Table 2 has 4 columns: 1. purchase_id 2. user_id 3. purchase_amount 4. purchase_date.

I would like to do something like that

```
SELECT Users.user_id, AVG(Purchases.purchase_amount)
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Purchases
WHERE MONTH(Users.date_of_join) = 06
AND AVG(Purchases.purchase_amount) BETWEEN Users.date_of_join AND DATE_ADD(date_of_join, INTERVAL 30);
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?that really help

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it.

Comment: Table 1 has 2 columns: 1. user_id 2. date_of_join
Table 2 has 3 columns: 1. purchase_id 2. user_id 3. purchase_amount

Comment: Shouldn't table 2 have a 'purchase_date' column too without which you simply cannot calculate the sum between two time periods?

Comment: forgot... yes sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would select all purchases for 6 months since date of sign up for user with id 5

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Purchases p
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.id=p.user_id
WHERE p.purchase_date BETWEEN u.date_of_join AND DATE_ADD(u.date_of_join, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND u.id=5;
```

Selecting the average is then trivial

```
SELECT AVG(p.purchase_amount)
FROM Purchases p
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.id=p.user_id
WHERE p.purchase_date BETWEEN u.date_of_join AND DATE_ADD(u.date_of_join, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND u.id=5;
```

---

If you want all the intervals as separate columns, then it becomes a bit more complex, but is still fairly easy.

```
SELECT avg_3.amount as avg_3, avg_6.amount as avg_6, avg_9.amount as avg_9
FROM Users u

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(p.purchase_amount) amount, p.user_id
    FROM Purchases p
    INNER JOIN Users u ON u.id=p.user_id
    WHERE p.purchase_date BETWEEN u.date_of_join AND DATE_ADD(u.date_of_join, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
    GROUP BY p.user_id
) as avg_3 ON u.id=avg_3.user_id

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(p.purchase_amount) amount, p.user_id
    FROM Purchases p
    INNER JOIN Users u ON u.id=p.user_id
    WHERE p.purchase_date BETWEEN u.date_of_join AND DATE_ADD(u.date_of_join, INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
    GROUP BY p.user_id
) as avg_6 ON u.id=avg_6.user_id

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(p.purchase_amount) amount, p.user_id
    FROM Purchases p
    INNER JOIN Users u ON u.id=p.user_id
    WHERE p.purchase_date BETWEEN u.date_of_join AND DATE_ADD(u.date_of_join, INTERVAL 9 MONTH)
    GROUP BY p.user_id
) as avg_9 ON u.id=avg_9.user_id

WHERE u.id=5;
```

Comment: i need the average purchases for each user since their joining date for 3, 6, 9 months.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need total revenue or average revenue per purchase?

If you just need total then you can try something like this -

```
SELECT U.USER_ID, SUM(PURCHASES.PURCHASE_AMOUNT)
  FROM USERS U
 INNER JOIN PURCHASES P
    ON U.USER_ID = P.USER_ID
 WHERE P.PURCHASE_DATE >= U.DATE_OF_JOIN
   AND P.PURCHASE_DATE < DATE_ADD(U.DATE_OF_JOIN, INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
 GROUP BY U.USER_ID;
```

For average, just replace `SUM` with `AVG`

Comment: i need the average

Comment: I reckon monthly average purchases for duration of 6 and 9 months?

Comment: thats awesome! would be possible to add another column for the second interval??